# How can I refresh one column at a time on Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to refresh one column at a time on Excel. I'm calling data from six Webservice links into 3 columns.

I guess that adds too much pressure on the server... so I get `#VALUE!` in the cell, 60% of the time (the formulae and all are correct).

I want to see if I can break it up... invoke only 2 links at a time. Thus I want to know if there is a way that I can:

- Click a Refresh button
- Run calculations (or Refresh) on first column
- Timer for 5 seconds
- Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#
- Run calculations (or Refresh) on second column
- Timer for 5 seconds
- Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#
- Run calculations(or Refresh) on third column
- ...

Bottom line:
I need help in refreshing one column at a time and yes, I've tried 
`Range(" ").Calculate`.

Unfortunately it doesn't work how I want it to (it either updates the whole worksheet or the button just stops working).

Comment: Perhaps you should abandon the Wait commands and use the Application.OnTime Method to schedule subsequent 'refreshes' at Now()+TImeSerial(0, 0, 5).

Comment: if you want to refresh the workbook just press f9 or fn+f9 on some laptop

Comment: (From Review): I adapted a different formatting which should be more reader-friendly. Please take care of the readability of your questions (and answers).